# Turn off webpack-hot-middleware client overlay in Nuxt application

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, webpack-hot-middleware

I'm trying to turn off the overlay from webpack-hot-middleware in my Nuxt application.

I tried editing the config in nuxt.config.js but the overlay persists.

```
  build: {
    // turn off client overlay when errors are present
    hotMiddleware: {
      overlay: false
    },
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at [this PR](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/4796/files), then you need to do this:

```js
  build: {
    hotMiddleware: {
      client: {
        // turn off client overlay when errors are present
        overlay: false
      }
    }
  }
```

It works for me (Nuxt 2.8.1).

Comment: Yep - that does it. Thank you!